# ROS_INFO error in the subscriber package

Tags: ros, ros-info

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to build a subscriber package to listen to `tf_static`. Here is the subscriber code:

```
//#include <iostream>
#include "ros/ros.h"
//#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "tf2_msgs/TFMessage.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Transform.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Vector3.h"

//using namespace std;

    void tfCallback(const tf2_msgs::TFMessage::ConstPtr& msg)
    {
        ROS_INFO("I heard: [%f]", msg->transforms.transform.translation.x);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    ros::init(argc, argv, "tf_subscriber_node");
    ros::NodeHandle ntf;
    ros::Subscriber sub = ntf.subscribe("/tf_static",1000, tfCallback);
    ros::spin ();
    return 0;
}
```

I am receiving the following error:

> src/tf_subscriber_node.cpp:13:47:
> error: 'const _transforms_type' has no
> member named 'transform'
> ROS_INFO("I heard: [%f]", msg->transforms.transform.translation.x);

I believe the error could be due to the `const` keyword. Or am I doing anything wrong in the part:

```
msg->transforms.transform.translation.x
```

Can anyone kindly guide on how to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239465/ros_info-error-in-the-subscriber-package/) by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2016-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have an array of `transforms` in that message. So you could do something like `msg->transforms[0].transform.translation.x`. Or you could put that in a for loop and print out each transform in the array of transforms. Since they are `double`s (not `float`) you also probably want to change `%f` to `%lf`.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2016-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-07-13**:
How did you figure out that it is an array; does the `[]` after `geometry_msgs/TransformStamped` in the [page](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf2_msgs/html/msg/TFMessage.html) indicate that?

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2016-07-13**:
Yes, the `[]` indicates an array.

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-07-13**:
Also, does `float64` indicate `double`?

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-07-13**:
I haven't yet tried your solution. I shall let you know, once I do it.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2016-07-13**:
Yes, `float64` indicates double. A float would be `float32`.

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-07-14**:
Thank You.